# Removing last forwardslash and the text before it

Tags: javascript

I have an URL looking like this:

https://www.website.com/dk/da/home/category/

I am trying to remove the last forward slash and the text before it, untill it reaches the new forwardslash. Meaning i would like the new URL to look like this:

https://www.website.com/dk/da/home/

I am trying to use substring to achieve this, but i run into problems because I always have a forward slash at the end of the URL.

```
var to = url.lastIndexOf('/');
to = to == -1 ? url.length : to + 1;
newUrl = url.substring(0, to);
```

Comment: Do you want a slash after `home` or no slash at the end of the URL at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regex

```js
let url = "https://www.website.com/dk/da/home/category/"
url = url.replace(/\w+\/$/, "")
console.log(url)
```

Explanation of the given example: https://regex101.com/r/3Nw7sL/2

**UPDATE**: as pointed out by @CertainPerformance in the comments of this answer, it is even easier to search for the last part of the url (\w+/) and replace it with an empty string.

Comment: A regular expression is the best method to use here, but it can be done much more cleanly: use `\w+\/$` and replace with the empty string.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I agree to say Regex are great, but seems like overkill for something as easy as this

Comment: @jonatjano If the alternative requires creating a couple of intermediate variables, I think regex is much cleaner

Answer (score 2):

[`string.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) can take a second parameters indicating from which index the search must be done (starting from the end)

so you can do this to get the last which is not the last character of the string :

```js
let url = "https://www.website.com/dk/da/home/category/"

var to = url.lastIndexOf('/', url.length - 2);
to = to == -1 ? url.length : to + 1;
newUrl = url.substring(0, to);

console.log(newUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

other way:

```
str='https://www.website.com/dk/da/home/category/';

arr = str.split('/');

arr.pop();
arr.pop();

str = arr.join('/');

str = str + '/';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about executing same logic twice :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String url = "https://www.website.com/dk/da/home/category/";
        int to = url.lastIndexOf('/');
        to = to == -1 ? url.length() : to;
        String newUrl = url.substring(0, to);
        to = newUrl.lastIndexOf('/');
        to = to == -1 ? newUrl.length() : to;
        newUrl = url.substring(0, to);
        System.out.println(newUrl);
    }
```

PS - Don't write it the logic twice instead use methods.